# Is there a better way to refactor this method?

Tags: c#

The method should return false if the bool is true and the length of array is not equal to 27 or if the array value 25 is empty.

The method should also return false if the bool is false and the length of array is not equal to 28 or if the array value 26 is empty

```
  private static bool IsValid(string[] values, bool isFullFile)
        {
            if (isFullFile && (values.Length != 27 || values[24] == string.Empty))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (!isFullFile && (values.Length != 28 || values[25] == string.Empty))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: In your second statement, you said: "if the bool is false and the length of array is not equal to 28 **or** if the array value 26 is empty". But, in the code, you are using an '&&'. Whenever I am faced with such scenarios, I try to put it in a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) to simplify.

Comment: This is highly subjective for SO sadly.  Your question _may_ be suitable for another Stack Exchange subsite devoted to _code reviews_.  Be sure to read the relating FAQ before posting though.  Good luck!

Comment: You might want to replace the _magic numbers_ in your code with pre-defined _constants_ so that you can 1) reduce errors 2) improve readability 3) reduce medium to long term maintenaince

Comment: I am using magic numbers for simplicity

Comment: You can shorten the code block if you want your code to look ugly, unreadable and to make others go crazy when looking at this code. Here is that version `return (isFullFile && (values.Length != 27 || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(values[24]))) ? false :
                   (!isFullFile && (values.Length != 28 || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(values[25]))) ? false : true;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be simplified enough to use an [Expression body definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator#expression-body-definition)

```
private static bool IsValid(string[] values, bool isFullFile)
    => isFullFile 
        ? (values.Length == 27 && values[24] != string.Empty) 
        : (values.Length == 28 && values[25] != string.Empty);
```

(Forgive me for answering this, because this really belongs in code review.)

Comment: I will remember that in future. Thanks for the solution